# Using socket.io and raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io, raspberry-pi3

I have a server already built through AWS, what I want is to send messages of data from the pi to the server, then for the server to take those messages and do some data analytics, and store the data in databases that will be sent to the pi. The databases and analytics is done. What I am not sure of is how to use Node.js and socket.io to send the data such as numbers to my server, and then the server to take the data received. I have looked up many things online, but have found nothing that is working for me.

Comment: If you're just sending data from the pi to your node.js server, then you can just use an http post as there's really no reason to use a continuous socket.io connection.  You can use a socket.io connection, but it is not needed.  Beyond that, I'm really not sure what your question is about.  A typical implementation would be to implement an http server using Express, implement some routes for accepting data and then do http POST requests from your raspberry pi to the node.js server to send it data.  Once on the server, use your favorite database to store the data.

Comment: is the server running node and socket.io already?